# Deployment of ASP.NET Core projects

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor-pages, publish

ASP.NET Core compiles Razor views/pages (`.cshtml` files) into assemblies or dlls by default when publishing a project.

The problem is if I make small html changes in those Razor views, we need to republish the whole project to get the updates out on the server. That's insane.

Is there any way to just publish `.cshtml` files similar to the way `.aspx` pages are published in the .NET Framework ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I should mention is I don't suggest you using the  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation feature during production, this feature is used for development, using RuntimeCompilation in production environment is not security.

Asp.net core razor page contains the RazorCompileOnPublish settings, if you set it to false, it will not compile the razor page to the dll.

Like this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <RazorCompileOnPublish>false</RazorCompileOnPublish>
    
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then it will generate the page folder inside the publish like this:

[image]

Then you could use AddRazorRuntimeCompilation method by installing the Install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation NuGet package like this:

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

Then your application allowing Razor files to be updated if they're edited while the app is running.

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot for the details. Yep, adding the RazorCompileOnPublish attribute does keep the Pages folder. But the thing is in production if we want to publish some small changes to those .cshtml files, like HTML updates. It doesn't work by publishing specific razor pages from Visual Studio. I can see the actual code has been added to .cshtml files, but on the site, it doesn't reflect the changes. It seems they are still retrieved from compiled dll.

Comment: So the question is: does that mean, even for tiny UI/HTML changes, we need to publish the whole project every time? That sounds bad since front-end developers might not feel comfortable doing a whole site release just for HTML changes. Thank you!

Comment: Modify any CSHTML codes include the html codes or else, you need redeploy the application. But if you are using the VS, it will check the remote server's file and just deploy the modified one.  So now, we will use angular or else as the frontend and use asp.net core web api as the backend.

Comment: Thank you so much for the insights. Ugh, that's super inconvenient. Not sure why they make things hard. Another question regarding publish, is there a way to have the dlls from project dependencies saved in a separate folder like "bin" instead of directly under the root of the published web application? Thank you.

Comment: But if you are using the VS, it will check the remote server's file and just deploy the modified one. - Yep, this is true, but this won't work if we select the option for"Delete existing files"

Comment: You are right. But actually inside the asp.net MVC not asp.net core MVC, it doesn't support just publish .cshtml files, since the razor engine is totally different than the aspx(web form). Any other question you have now?